# inserting fields in GROUP HEADER section of Crystal Reports

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am grouping based on a client id of a database using Crystal Reports. The grouping is done fine, but I want to display the grouping client details in the group header section. When I drag a field from the field explorer into the group header section, the first record that is grouped is being displayed.

Comment: how many client records are there in database? since you are grouping by client there will be one group for one client....

Answer (score 0):

Grouping is used as a master entry and its always the same for all its child or detail entry. So if you make client-id as a group, then its shows client detail like client name, its addres, logo(if any) , contact no. etc.

It will always change when client-id will change. other wise it always shows the same details for all detail section till client-id same.

please read for gouping.

http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Crystal_Reports_XI.asp?Page=3_2

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142064/Step-by-Step-Creation-of-Crystal-Report-using-its

Comment: hello ajay..thanks very much bro.. but how to insert fields into the group header section to display the grouped field details...any idea..kindly give me your number i will call you back....

Comment: because when i add the fields from the field explorer the first row of the grouped item is displayed not the field details of the item that is grouped